# Modifying Charts Without Changing It's Properties

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am doing a script to change some data in a chart (the title in this example) and when I run this function i'ts changing some properties on it and the chart changes completely.

This is the code I am using:

```
function ChangeChart() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test');
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('title', 'Title Test')
  .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

This is how the chart looked before I run the script:
[image]

And after:
[image]

I am using this data range:

[image]

And this is the properties before and after I run the function:
[image]

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code snippet, its similar to the one from the [Google Apps Developer Blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/06/programmatically-managing-charts-in.html) other than the `EmbeddedChartBuilder` not set as a variable and you're directly modifying it in `chart`. Could it be due to that? Try to set the `EmbeddedChartBuilder` in to a variable similar to the code snippet from the blog post.